# What is mnemonic for "W" in WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS, etc?

Tags: c, libc

What is mnemonic for "W" i.e. what does "W" mean in the following macros:

```
int WIFEXITED (int status)
int WEXITSTATUS (int status)
int WIFSIGNALED (int status)
int WTERMSIG (int status)
int WCOREDUMP (int status)
int WIFSTOPPED (int status)
int WSTOPSIG (int status)
```

Also see [Process Status Completion](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Process-Completion-Status.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is simply related to *W*-aiting functions like the [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) syscall.

Answer (score 11):

I suspect it's for `wait`. These constants are for status provided by `wait`, `waitpid`, etc. functions.